# Embedded quicktime video pause on click how to prevent?

Tags: windows, firefox, quicktime, embedded-video

I embedded a quicktime video in firefox. It works, but i would like to prevent the users to stop the video by clicking on it with the left mouse button. Reading the apple documentation i didn't find any answear. I came up with a workaround, i just put an almost invisible div over the whole video. The workaround works in firefox for os X, but oddly does not for the same version of firefox in windows.

I would appreciate a way, workaround or not, to achive this at least in the windows/firefox environment. Thanks!

Comment: you might have to embed it in a flash video.  Also, you might have to accept answers to some of your questions :)

Comment: i was missing the accept feature, sorry. now i got it.
btw, flash is evil. i would use html5 <video> but mozilla do not support quicktime at the time being, and i got some legacy from the committer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so this is how the embedded QuickTime object works:

- if you click it, it PAUSES the stream
- if you give it HREF parameter, and then click it, it opens the given URL, but doesn't pause the stream

So the idea is to give it the URL that will not open, and will prevent the player from pausing, so add this parameter: `href="javascript:function(){}"` in the `<embed>` tag like so:

```
<embed src="poster.mov" bgcolor="000000" width="640" height="480" scale="ASPECT" qtsrc="rtsp://192.168.0.2/stream1" kioskmode="true" showlogo=false" autoplay="true" controller="false" href="javascript:function(){}" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/">
```

And there you go, no pausing when you click it, and it works on all browsers because you are using the HREF parameter. =)